# Azure HDInsight with ADL created by REST API

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

Getting the below error when creating Azure HDinsight with ADL by Rest API.

Below is the config we have given as part of json . Is there anything missing ?

```
"core-site": {
                    "fs.defaultFS": "adl://<Home>",
                    "dfs.adls.home.mountpoint": "<rootPath>"
                }
```

{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Datalake container configuration is required for creating clusters with datalake default filesystem. Please retry request with container configuration.,User input validation failed. Errors: The request payload is invalid."}[

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create the Datalake container first and provide the container configuration. Not sure, whether I answered your question. here is a configuration which create the cluster with ADL (using templates)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-hdinsight-datalake-store-azure-storage/azuredeploy.json